# Download with CefSharp.WinForms

Tags: vb.net, cefsharp

I use CefSharp to include a web browser into my application but when I added DownloadHandler.vb (translated from C# to VB) I have this:

```
' Copyright © 2013 The CefSharp Authors. All rights reserved.
'
' Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

Imports System
Imports CefSharp

Namespace CefSharp.Example.Handlers
    Public Class DownloadHandler
        Inherits IDownloadHandler

        Public Event OnBeforeDownloadFired As EventHandler(Of DownloadItem)
        Public Event OnDownloadUpdatedFired As EventHandler(Of DownloadItem)

        Public Sub OnBeforeDownload(ByVal chromiumWebBrowser As IWebBrowser, ByVal browser As IBrowser, ByVal downloadItem As DownloadItem, ByVal callback As IBeforeDownloadCallback)
            RaiseEvent OnBeforeDownloadFired(Me, downloadItem)

            If Not callback.IsDisposed Then

                Using callback
                    callback.Continue(downloadItem.SuggestedFileName, showDialog:=True)
                End Using
            End If
        End Sub

        Public Sub OnDownloadUpdated(ByVal chromiumWebBrowser As IWebBrowser, ByVal browser As IBrowser, ByVal downloadItem As DownloadItem, ByVal callback As IDownloadItemCallback)
            RaiseEvent OnDownloadUpdatedFired(Me, downloadItem)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

So I have the error "Classes can only inherit other classes" (I'm French so My Visual Studio is in French and I translate that how I can, sorry for bad English ;)) and in Form1.vb I see that error:

> 'Cef' isn't a member of WindowsApp1.CefSharp

If I remove DownloadHandler.vb this error disappears, please help me

Comment: It's a pretty accurate translation; it might make sore sense to say "the only thing you can inherit from is a class" though. Try `Implements` - classes implement interfaces, they don't inherit them https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/implements-statement - I put this as a comment because I don't think that ultimately it's the full question you inteded/need to ask

Comment: This doesn't really helps because I always have the error "'Cef' isn't a member of WindowsApp1.CefSharp" and now I have 2 others errors that says that I need to implements some things that I can't implement but I think that I'm on the right way. So thanks !

Comment: Just because the error count rises when you fix one problem, does not mean you made things worse; it just means you fixed one problem that allowed the VB compiler to detect two more. TBH you should really post the C#, the VB you have, the errors you have and then we can advise better. There isn't a lot of difference between VB and C#; this will just be basic syntax problems probably

Comment: You need an `Implements` clause on the routines that implement the interface members.  Unlike C#, VB does not have implicit implementation of interface members.

Comment: An error message referring to `WindowsApp1.CefSharp` suggests that you're missing a reference to the appropriate Cef# library in your project references.